# How to get the response of a rest call inside the api in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2-esb

I am calling the rest service as sown in below

```
<resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/getallpayments" faultSequence="error_handler_">
  <inSequence>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="CashreceiptsService" value="**************Entered into getallpayments*************"/>
        <property name="Request Payload" expression="get-property('JSON_OBJECT')"/>
     </log>
     <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="GET" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
     <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
     <oauthService remoteServiceUrl="https://localhost:9443/services/OAuth2TokenValidationService/" username="admin" password="admin"/>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="CashreceiptService" value="^^^^^^^^^^^^OAUTH COMPLETED^^^^^^^^^^^^"/>
        <property name="User Name******" expression="get-property('username')"/>
     </log>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <http format="rest" method="GET" uri-template="http://localhost:8080/rest/commonService/getallpayments"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>

     <drop/>
  </inSequence>
```

It will gives the below response

```
[{"typeId":1,"name":"Entity_Type","value":"EMPLOYER","description":"Employer","createdDate":"08/12/2013","tenantId":0,"hasPhiFields":false},{"typeId":2,"name":"Entity_Type","value":"BROKER","description":"Broker","createdDate":"08/12/2013","tenantId":0,"hasPhiFields":false}]
```

I am able to get the above response in the UI.
But i need the response of "typeId" inside the Api and that typeId i need to get and pass to the another service as a input parameter and this service will give the final response to the UI.
Right now i am implementing using the service chaining.

Main issue is how to get the response of one service and pass to another service as input param? please suggest me, i am new to WSO2 ESB.

And also how to get the POST data send by user?

Answer (score 0):

you may grab the values in out sequence else any other sequence for getting response from their you may send to another endpoint or proxy or any endpoint
in your case you get the values in out sequence or any other sequence u need adopt particuler object like this

```
<property xmlns:f="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="typeid" expression="//f:typeid/text" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

or else u define as per your endpoint

```
<send receive="someothersequencename">
        <endpoint>
           <http format="rest" method="GET" uri-template="http://localhost:8080/rest/commonService/getallpayments"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
```

then u will get all response in this sequence